# Rotation Effect for a Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

**Hello,**

I am working on an extension and would like the icon to spin when you click on the extension. I have no idea how to start. I am thinking I would need a manifest and a java script file but I can't get anything to work....

-Ekrcoaster

Code so far:

```
function updateIcon(back) {
  if (back) {
    chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path: {
    "16": "icon16.png",
    "32": "icon32.png"}
    });


  } else {
  chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path: {
    "16": "icon.png",
    "32": "icon.png"}
    });


 }}

window.setInterval(rotate, 10);
var i = 0;
function rotate() {
    if(i > -1) {
    i++;
    updateIcon(getPercent2(i));
    //console.log(i);
} else {

}

}

function getPercent2(number) {
   var x = number % 2
   if(x == 1) {
    return true;
   } else {
    return false;
   }

}
```

I tried images but I can't get the images to load either.....

Comment: I have, I was only testing changing the icon. Is there any rotation to the icons?

Comment: By _icon_ you mean the extension icon that appears in the browser along with the rest of the other's extensions icons?

Comment: Yes. I am not sure what they are official called...

Comment: I have seen some extensions that have the icon spin around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only possible way to emulate an icon animation is to change the extension icon image every certain time (as short as it's visually needed for it to seem smooth).

You will need 1 image to match each of the possible rotation angles, if the rotation changes 10 degrees at a time, then you would need 36 different images (360/10).

A possible attempt would be something like this

```
var degree = 0;

function rotate() {
  /* we update the icon to the current rotation degree */
  var path = 'icon' + degree + '.png';
  chrome.browserAction.setIcon({ path: path });

  /* we update the rotation degree adding 10 or setting back to 0 */
  degree = degree === 360 ? 0 : degree + 10;

  /* we use recursivity here to keep animating */
  setTimeout(rotate, 200);
}

/* start */
rotate();
```

You could also add a boolean to check and end the loop if needed.

Comment: I tried that but I got this error message:  

'Unchecked runtime.lastError while running browserAction.setIcon: Icon invalid.'